# Using inline CSV data in Vega charts

Tags: json, csv, vega

I'm trying to use inline csv data with Vega charts, using the values property of the Vega data specification. The [Vega documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/data/#format) says that this possible, but doesn't give an example. I have tried to change the [bar chart example](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/bar-chart/) from the examples gallery to use inline CSV data instead of JSON, but without success.

I replaced the data section from the example code with my own code. The original snippet looks like this:

```
"data": [
{
  "name": "table",
  "values": [
    {"category": "A", "amount": 28},
    {"category": "B", "amount": 55},
    {"category": "C", "amount": 43},
    {"category": "D", "amount": 91},
    {"category": "E", "amount": 81},
    {"category": "F", "amount": 53},
    {"category": "G", "amount": 19},
    {"category": "H", "amount": 87}
  ]
} ]
```

I replaced it with this one:

```
  "data": [
{
  "name": "table",
  "format": "csv",
  "values": {"category", "amount"
    "A", "28"
    "B", "55"
    "C", "43"
    "E", "91"
    "E", "81"
    "F", "53"
    "G", "19"
    "H", "87"}
} ]
```

I used the [Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/), but got only error messages about unexpected tokens in the JSON. I also tried the following variation:

```
  "data": [
{
  "name": "table",
  "format": "csv",
  "values": "category, amount
    A, 28
    B, 55
    C, 43
    E, 91
    E, 81
    F, 53
    G, 19
    H, 87"
} ]
```

But this lead to the same error messages. What is the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way, as you can view in the documentation, is something like this:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {"values": "a,b\nA,50\nB,30\nC,60", "format": {"type": "csv"}},
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

An example [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIaZJ1h2DcyGA7nRiHETOMtXLDypJhUiioBKKigxEiCDGpoIEgKTAA6svoKYgAMKQBCCgDMWbIAwgoAbBnBAGZs6siYaKCYAJ44cHFQEMQgAL7dSsjqANZx1urBcLJQbMo0smQNIAAeC5U0cILKcShKza1xsmwIs1HBSIs0EAuCSJ6C+nMWaBm9Sk0raxsjwbtt6ACODCQsh0gR0pB6vSAA)